# Is it possible through the REST api to retreive which sites a specific user is following in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

Using the SharePoint REST api or search API, is it possible to retrieve a full list of all the sites a specific user is following? All I can find in the documentation is `https://<sharepoint>/_api/social.following/my/followed(types=4)` which only works for the current logged in user.

Comment: Any followup questions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. The below are the only available endpoints:

- Follow
- StopFollowing
- IsFollowed
- My
- My/FollowedDocumentsUri
- My/FollowedSitesUri
- My/Followed
- My/FollowedCount
- My/Followers
- My/Suggestions
- GetMySuggestions
- IsMyPeopleListPublic
- AmIFollowedBy
- GetPeopleFollowedBy
- GetFollowersFor

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/following-people-and-content-rest-api-reference-for-sharepoint#resource-endpoints-for-following-people-and-following-content-tasks)